# Zorn's Lemma, $A=\{a,b\}$ simple example

Tags: abstract-algebra

My question has to do with Zorn's Lemma.

> Zorn's Lemma: If $P$ is a non-empty partially ordered set such that every totally ordered subset is bounded above in $P$ then $P$ contains at least one maximal element.

First, let $A=\{a,b\}$ and $\leq = \{(a,a),(b,b)\}$. Then $\leq$ is a partial ordering of $A$.

The totally ordered subsets of $A$ would be $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ and each is bounded above by $a$ and $b$ respectively. From here we would conclude by Zorn's Lemma that $A$ contains a maximal element but this is not the case, I am making a mistake somewhere and I don't know where. This is not homework I am just doing extra thinking on the side.

Comment: There is a distinction between *maximal* (nothing is larger than it) and *maximum* (larger than everything else).

Comment: In your example, there are two maximal elements, $a$ and $b.$ What is your definition of maximal element??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A *maximal* element is an element $m$ such that $\forall x [ m \leq x \to m = x]$. A *maximum* is an element $m$ such that $\forall x[x \leq m]$. Zorn's Lemma says that there is a maximal element, not necessarily a maximum.

In your case, both $a$ and $b$ are maximal elements.

Comment: Okay thank you, I was thinking it must be a definition. I was thinking maximum element, I didn't really know the difference between maximum and maximal.

Answer (score 1):

The subset $\{a\}$ is only bounded above by $a$ as there is no relation between $a$ and $b$. Likewise for $\{b\}$, $b$ is the only upper bound, so $A$ has two maximal elements: $a,b$.